# I want to select a value from dropdrown which should change the listings in html page and the map page

Tags: javascript, html

I have created html page with listings and i have another page with google maps page for those listings. I need to have a dropdown a the html page where i can change the value in it based on the selected value the listings in html and map page should display.

Comment: good idea. what you have done so far  can you share with us?

Comment: <html>
<body>
<h1><b>Store Details</b></h1>
<div id="listings"><b>4 COUSINS </b><div id='add'>2 / 383 NEPEAN HWAY PARKDALE,VIC 3195</div><br><b>
A BONGIOVANNI & SON</b><div id='add'>178 VICTORIA STREET SEDDON,VIC 3011</div><br><b>
ALMA ORGANICS      </b><div id='add'>CNR MAIN STREET & MURNONG STREET POINT COOK,VIC 3030</div><br><b>
AUNT MAGGIES HAMPTON</b><div id='add'>446 HAMPTON STREET HAMPTON,VIC 3188</div><br>
</div>
</body>
</html>    This is the code of html page created the map for these listings with google maps api

Comment: that is in the different page

Comment: <select onchange="filterMarkers(this.value)" 
style="position: absolute; z-index: 100; right: 30px; top: 10px; ">
    <option value="ALL">ALL</option>
    <option value="VIC">VIC</option>
    <option value="NSW">NSW</option>
    <option value="TAS">TAS</option>
    <option value="ACT">ACT</option>
  </select>
<div id="map"></div>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js">
 </script>

Comment: <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="scripts/jquery-2.0.0.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBH8itGXztXq49md0y8wyJhQoq6PMeEYm0&amp;sensor=false"> </script>

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">

Comment: var map, bounds, center;
var gmarkers1 = [];
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
initialize();
$(".location").each(function() {
    var e = $(this).find("lat").html(),
        n = $(this).find("lng").html(),
        o = $(this).find("p"),
        a = new google.maps.LatLng(e, n);
    addMarkerToMap(a, o.html())
});
fitBoundsToVisibleMarkers();
google.maps.event.addDomListener(map, "idle", function() {
    center = map.getCenter()
});

$(window).resize(function() {
    map.setCenter(center)
});

Comment: function initialize() {
    var e = [{
        featureType: "all",
        elementType: "all",
        stylers: [{
            saturation: -100
        }]
    }];

Comment: for (var i = 0; i < gmarkers1.length; i++) {
        if (gmarkers1[i].getVisible()) {
            bounds.extend(gmarkers1[i].getPosition());
        }
    }
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
}

function addMarkerToMap(e, n) {
    var o =

Comment: "http://static1.squarespace.com/static/51da8b30e4b001cbc64f06fb/t/54ff3065e4b01f6eb7805f15/1426010213528/PinBananinha2.png";
    var a = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: e,
        icon: o,
        addr: n
    });
    gmarkers1.push(a);
    google.maps.event.addListener(a, "click", function() {
        infoWindow.close(), infoWindow.setContent(n), infoWindow.open(
            map, a)
    })
}
   
  </script>

Comment: that is all about the code for map which i used. I need to integrate the above html with the below map code using a single select state

Answer (score 0):

Update 1.0

Well here the trick using js. Let's pretend the container who have id=map is a map. So when user click on the select list it will show you the map. To make your background map look beautiful with the map i suggest use this.

Advice to you this is not good for practice. But for beginner this is how to settle with.

https://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/

Example

HTML

```
    <div class="container" id="test">
    <p> Hello World</p>
    <select id="status" onChange="myFunction()">
            <option value="1">Select Map </option>
            <option value="2">Australia </option>
            <option value="3">Japan </option>
            <option value="4">Malaysia </option>
             <option value="5">Korea </option>
    </select>
    <button >Submit</button>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="container" id="map" style="display:none;">
    <p> Container aussie</p>
</div>

<div class="container" id="map1" style="display:none;">
    <p> Container Japan</p>
</div>

<div class="container" id="map2" style="display:none;">
    <p> Container Malaysia</p>
</div>

<div class="container" id="map3" style="display:none;">
    <p> Container Korea</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container{
    width: 50%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 2px 15px 13px 20px;
}
```

JS

```
  function myFunction() {
    if (document.getElementById('status').value == "1"){
    document.getElementById("map").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("map1").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("map2").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("map3").style.display="none";
}
    if (document.getElementById('status').value == "2"){
    document.getElementById("map").style.display="block";
    document.getElementById("map1").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("map2").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("map3").style.display="none";
}
    if (document.getElementById('status').value == "3"){
    document.getElementById("map").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("map1").style.display="block";
    document.getElementById("map2").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("map3").style.display="none";
}
    if (document.getElementById('status').value == "4"){
    document.getElementById("map").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("map1").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("map2").style.display="block";
    document.getElementById("map3").style.display="none";
}
    if (document.getElementById('status').value == "5"){
    document.getElementById("map").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("map1").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("map2").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("map3").style.display="block";
}
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bepn5632/1/)

There is a lot way better than this. Like i said this is just a trick. Hope you can implement way better than demo that i did.

Comment: Not exactly this. I have two pages one is in html displayed with listings another with the map with those listings. I need to place a dropdown in html page based on states in australia. If i change any state in dropdown only listings belong to those state should displayed in html as well as map.

Comment: if i add multiple maps with states showing as error from google.

Comment: saying something you cannot use multiple maps

Comment: probably you put too many map api there. try rid of it if you are including maps api more than one time, if you are, then remove the one.